# Channel Set Export?

Tags: channel, export, category-group, settings

EE 3.3.2 References the new Channel Set (importing/exporting channel configurations for setting up new sites).

While I will EXTREMELY miss the MSM site replication tools, in theory I understand that a "Channel Set" (Channel fields, category groups, status groups, etc) will get me close....HOWEVER, despite the documentation referencing the capability to Export/Import a Channel set, despite my searching, **I have not yet found where I can export a channel set**.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/channel/index.html#channel-set-export) its tucked away in the Manage section of the CP.

Comment: AH - Found it...when examining the list of channels, EACH channel can be exported individually (the little cloud icon on the tools for each channel).